# Mongoose - Best approach for storing Set in schema

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

My model contains Set, and I would like to model my schema in the most elegant way to have working serialization and deserialization. What should I do? I know there are schema types for Array, Map, Array of Arrays, but what to do with Set and when I should transform my Set because it won't be possible to store Set in DB, I assume...

So, is there a chance to have in my model Set, and Array in a schema? If not how should I map that Set to Array and in which moment.

Answer (score 1):

Use Array type could be fine, and cooperate with `$addToSet`, `$pull` and other array operators